# How do I re-activate the movement in my Emoji-Me emojis?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I purchased Emoji-Me third party app for my iPhone XR. The emojis move on my phone but not when I post them on Facebook for example.

How do I enable or fix the movements so that they are animated again?